# Is it okay to put <ruby> tag inside <hx> tags?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm developing a UI for a Japanese website where I have to use a Japanese word together with its English equivalent. I wonder if it's okay to use `<ruby>` tag inside any heading tags `<h1>`-`<h6>`.

I'm using the W3C Validation extension in VS Code and it shows no error. I have searched the internet for similar cases but I found nothing.

```
<h3 class="division-menu__heading">
    <ruby class="division-menu__annotation">
        折込広告
        <rtc lang="en"><rt>Insertion of the advertisement</rt></rtc>
    </ruby>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** **[`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby)** is an acceptable child of any element that allows **[phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)**.

[image: Ruby]

And `<h1>` through `<h6>` [all accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) phrasing content:

[image]

Comment: I get it. Thank you!